# Select in Select Rank()

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone point me in the direction of how I can select a particular username and their rank from the resulting query? I'm trying to retrieve FoxDown's rank.

I believe I need to select from this query somehow `Select username, my_rank (Select....`.

Current Query

```
    SELECT
    username,
    SUM(goals) as Diff,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Diff DESC) my_rank
    FROM results
    WHERE Week = 'Week 23'
    GROUP by username
    ORDER by my_rank
```

Query resulting table

```
username  Diff  my_rank
Sugar      12     1
Coj        10     2
Gunners     8     3
Captain     6     4
Spoon       6     4
Ric         6     4
FoxDown     6     4
shau        4     8
Josh        4     8
nol         4     8
pesty       4     8
Hill        4     8
Jg          4     8
```

Answer (score 1):

[Window functions are calculated *after* the where clause, logically](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/). So you have to nest your window function calculation in a derived table, and then filter on that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    username,
    SUM(goals) as Diff,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(goals) DESC) my_rank
  FROM results
  WHERE Week = 'Week 23'
  GROUP by username
) t
WHERE username = 'FoxDown'
```

Note that you cannot reference a column alias from the same `SELECT` level, so you need to repeat the `SUM(goals)` aggregate function in the rank calculation. This works again because aggregate functions are calculated *before* window functions, logically (see the same linked blog post)

Comment: You don't need a subquery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes you do! :) Unless you're using teradata, which has the `QUALIFY` clause, where your `username = 'FoxDown'` predicate would go...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: No worries :) I do wish there was a better way, i.e. `QUALIFY`...

Answer (score 1):

This worked!!

```
WITH players_results AS(
    SELECT
        username,
        SUM(goals) as Diff,
        RANK() OVER (    
            ORDER BY Diff DESC      
        ) my_rank
    FROM
        players_results
        WHERE matchweek = 'Matchweek 24'
        GROUP by username
        ORDER by my_rank
    )
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        players_results
    WHERE 
        username = 'FoxDown'
```